# How to check if a CMake build directory build type is Debug or Release?

Tags: cmake

I know the build type can be set using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` or `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` but is there a command line way to check/confirm which build type is being used by CMake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides looking in `CMakeCache.txt` you could - in the build directory - use

```
cmake -L . | grep CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
```

or you could e.g. add a customized target to your `CMakeLists.txt` for doing it

```
add_custom_target(print_build_type COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
```

will then be called with something like

```
$ make --silent print_build_type
Release
```

But [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) could be empty.

So here is a more generic version using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
add_custom_target(
    print_build_type 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<$<CONFIG:>:Undefined>$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:>>:$<CONFIG>>
)
```

**References**

- [What happens for C/C++ builds if CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498109/what-happens-if-cmake-build-type-is-empty)
- [CMake - Find out which build type is currently used](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Find-out-which-build-type-is-currently-used-td5324199.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can grep the value from the CMakeCache.txt file in the build dir. Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm working out of a cmake directory and I want to be able to determine whether I'm in debug or release.