# Proper way to determine generator for cmake project

Tags: cmake

I'm in a cmake build directory and want to build the project, but don't know if cmake was run with `-G Unix\ Makefile` or `-G Ninja`.

Now I know I can just be ignorant of that and use `cmake --build .`, but when I want to provide additional options `cmake --build . -- SOMETHING` I should know if I should provide gnumake or ninja options.

As possible solutions I found that I can just check the presence of a `Makefile` or `build.ninja` file. Or grep in the `CMakeCache.txt` for `CMAKE_GENERATOR`.

**EDIT**:

In a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164166/how-to-check-if-a-cmake-build-directory-build-type-is-debug-or-release) it is explained that values passed to cmake with `-D` can be queried with `cmake -LA -N`. But this doesn't list the `-G` parameter.

I am wondering if there is a more proper way (just like `cmake -LA -N` instead of grepping for variable values).

Comment: The `CMAKE_GENERATOR` sounds right to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a CMake build directory build type is Debug or Release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164166/how-to-check-if-a-cmake-build-directory-build-type-is-debug-or-release)

Comment: unfortunately no duplicate, `cmake -LA N` doesn't list `CMAKE_GENERATOR`. It seems to me, it only lists `-D<variablename>` variables, not the value of `-G`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've cited two possible solutions:

- **Check presence of build system files**. Not a general solution, as it only works for some generators, but it may work in your case. This would not work for Visual Studio (for example, unless you parse the Visual Studio files themselves), as each generator version creates the same filenames.
- **Grep CMakeCache.txt for `CMAKE_GENERATOR`**. Relies on platform specific tools (grep), and the location of the CMakeCache.txt. Both likely not a problem in most situations.

A slight modification to the second option, which makes it more portable, is to cache the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` in another variable:

```
set(USED_CMAKE_GENERATOR "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" CACHE STRING "Expose CMAKE_GENERATOR" FORCE)
```

Then, when you use `cmake -L`, `USED_CMAKE_GENERATOR` will show up.

Comment: For what I had in mind, your variation doesn't work (it should work in any cmake build directory, w/o need to edit the CMakeLists.txt before). Otherwise it's nice. Ultimately I went for the first option.