# Does CMake always generate configurations for all possible project configurations?

Tags: c++, configuration, cmake, projects-and-solutions

I have specific configuration for debug and release options (diferent for MSVC and for GCC). Say we generate default project via `cmake ..`. Does CMake always generate configurations for all possible project configurations (Debug and Release) or one always gets only one set of comfiguration options?

Comment: I think it depends on your generator. It certainly does do all configurations for visual studio. I am not so sure about the other generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @cplusplusrat has commented, this depends on the generator/build environment:

- For multi-configuration environments like MSVC or XCode, yes.
- For single-configuration environments like GCC, no.

And the default for single-configuration environments is neither `Debug` nor `Release` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498109/what-happens-for-c-c-builds-if-cmake-build-type-is-empty) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164166/how-to-check-if-a-cmake-build-directory-build-type-is-debug-or-release)).

So I have always defined one  [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) for single-configuration environments as a default. You could also do this e.g. in build scripts calling CMake:

**mingw_build.cmd**

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: usage:
::          mingw_build.cmd <target> <config>
::                  <target> - target to be built (default: all)
::                  <config> - configuration to be used for build (default: Debug)

if NOT "%1" == "" (set CMAKE_TARGET=%1) else (set CMAKE_TARGET=all)
if NOT "%2" == "" (set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%2) else (set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug)
SET CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=%CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%

IF NOT EXIST "%CMAKE_BINARY_DIR%\Makefile" (
    cmake -H"." -B"%CMAKE_BINARY_DIR%" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE% -G"MinGW Makefiles"
)
cmake --build %CMAKE_BINARY_DIR% --target %CMAKE_TARGET%

ENDLOCAL
```

**vs_x64_build.cmd**

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: usage:
::          vs_x64_build.cmd <target> <config>
::                  <target> - target to be built (default: ALL_BUILD)
::                  <config> - configuration to be used for build (default: Debug)

if NOT "%1" == "" (SET CMAKE_TARGET=%1) else (SET CMAKE_TARGET=ALL_BUILD)
if NOT "%2" == "" (set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%2) else (set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug)
SET CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=x64

IF NOT EXIST "%CMAKE_BINARY_DIR%\*.sln" (
    cmake -H"." -B"%CMAKE_BINARY_DIR%" -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
)
cmake --build "%CMAKE_BINARY_DIR%" --target "%CMAKE_TARGET%" --config "%CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%"

ENDLOCAL
```