# How do I handle CMake.exe errors

Tags: batch-file, cmake

I have a batch file that starts CMake.exe with some arguments and I need to break the execution if there were any errors in CMake (that's a part of product build process). The problem is that %ERRORLEVEL% from CMake.exe process seems to be always is 0 whereas stadard error output might contain errors such as

```
...
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeConfigs/My.cmake:77 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    Resources/ActionIcons/ActionIcon_ABC.png

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  My/Path/CMakeLists.txt:149 (my_add_target)


-- Generating done
...
```

I plan to dump standard error output to a file and grep/findstr error, but can error handling be done more elegantly?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know whether the cmake project generation ended with success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253153/how-to-know-whether-the-cmake-project-generation-ended-with-success)

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the batch-file code if you don't provide it in your question?

Answer (score 3):

The most often mistake is using `%ERRORLEVEL%` in a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)`.

The entire command block is preprocessed by Windows command interpreter before running any command in the command block or the **IF** or **FOR** command usually used on line with opening `(`. During this preprocessing all `%variable%` references are replaced by current values of the referenced environment variables. Then the command block is executed with the preprocessed code.

This behavior can be seen by removing `@echo off` at top of the batch file, or modify it to `@echo on` or `rem @echo off` and run the batch file from within a command prompt window. Now Windows command interpreter outputs to console window every command line and command block after preprocessing as really executed next.

The help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains on an **IF** and a **FOR** example how to reference an environment variable within a command line or command block modified in same command line or command block on execution using **delayed environment variable expansion**.

But for this case there is no need for `%ERRORLEVEL%` expanded during preprocessing phase or delayed expanded using `!ERRORLEVEL!` at all.

There is the good old `IF ERRORLEVEL X ...` syntax working since MS-DOS up to currently latest Windows 10.

*CMake* exits with exit code `0` on success and a greater number on error as nearly all console applications.

`IF ERRORLEVEL X ...` means **IF** exit code (return value of function `main`) assigned to environment variable `ERRORLEVEL` is **greater or equal** `X` **THEN** ...

Then I suggest to look on:

- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)

A successful **IF** does not modify value of `ERRORLEVEL`. And `EXIT /B` without a number also does not modify `ERRORLEVEL`.

So on next line after the command line running *CMake* there is only this command line needed to exit the processing of current batch file and return to calling batch file or process on any error encountered by *CMake*:

```
if errorlevel 1 exit /B
```

The calling batch file or process gets the exit code of *CMake* as a result of the batch file execution because **IF** and **EXIT** don't modify `ERRORLEVEL` in this case. It's really so easy!